# google appscript DocumentApp invalid argument error

Tags: javascript

Very simple use of the API, just like the example at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyurlurl but I'm getting this error and can't understand why. I get the same error if I try openById() instead.

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 1):

After some further testing, I believe this error is because the mimetype of the file is not a native google drive document (doc, sheet, slide) but instead a pdf file. I was able to get this working when declaring the mimetype.

```
var srcfolderId = "1vaAInpB8ACPiYi12A7F2yuOEU7EwNzbI"; // <--- Please input folder ID.
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);

while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileBlob = file.getBlob();

    var resource = {
      title: fileBlob.getName(),
      mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
    };

    var options = {
      ocr: true
    };


    //Enable Drive API under advanced api's
    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
    Logger.log(docFile.title+" " + docFile.alternateLink);

    // Extract Text from PDF file
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
    var text = doc.getBody().getText();
}
```